# Win32 files locked for reading: how to find out who's locking them

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, file-io

In C++ (specifically on Visual C++), sometimes you cannot open a file because another executable has it opened and is not sharing it for reads.  If I try to open such a file, how can I programatically find out who's locking the file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Windows 2000 and higher, you cannot do this without using a kernel-mode driver. Process Explorer and other similar tools load a driver automatically to accomplish this. This is because the file handles are in kernel space and not accessible by user-mode applications (EXE files).

If you are really interested in doing this, take a look at [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/OpenedFileFinder.aspx?msg=2249607).

Comment: You can see that Process Explorer is loading a driver by looking at the DLLs of the `System` process; you will see a driver similar to `PROCEXP113.SYS` loaded

Answer (score 5):

The MSDN approved way is [`IFileIsInUse::GetAppName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775867.aspx). Requires Vista, though.

Comment: This seems to require cooperation from the program that opened a file, which is not the same as what is being asked.

Comment: It's the most information-rich way, which is why you should try it first.

Comment: Sure, there's no harm in trying it, but the chances that it works are very low so the OP will most likely need an alternative regardless.