# How to know when a file is edited?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is there a way ( or an API ) to know when a text file is edited ( by a program or by a person ) and do a specific action ?

For example: I want to show a MessageBox when the file c:\Users\john\free.txt is edited.

Comment: You could always check the modified timestamp, and see if it changes to something newer.

Comment: There is no API that would directly give you that information, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990535/win32-files-locked-for-reading-how-to-find-out-whos-locking-them. And, btw, there is no difference whether program or person is modifying a file - a person needs to use some program, isn't it? :)

Comment: Look at the answers of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517460/is-there-anything-like-inotify-on-windows

Comment: @Bojan, yes there is.  Use FindFirstChangeNotification and ReadDirectoryChanges.

Comment: @Patrick Thanks. There was a question earlier today about Microsoft API which notifies on registry changes (`RegNotifyChangeKeyValue`) and after I posted my comment here I was thinking why some similar API wouldn't exist for the file system. And here it is! (+1 for your answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on when you exactly want to know it.

- is your application running continuously and do you want to see any change as soon as possible?
- is your application a simple command-line application that needs to check for changes once?

In the second case, you could check the modification dates of the file (as suggested by PoweRoy and Michal) or use a hash (as suggested by PoweRoy).

If your application is running continuously, you should use the FindFirstChangeNotification and ReadDirectoryChanges functions.  You can read more about it on the following pages:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: Combining the hash approach with the change notification would be an even better approach for performance and security issues

Answer (score 1):

Simplest: compare modification dates. But this can be manipulated.

Or make a hash of the original file and compare it with the current file.

Comment: I would go for the hash as it guarantees that no hack was done.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the infinite loop ?

Answer (score 0):

GetFileTime should help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

and there is GetFileAttributesEx as well.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the infinite loop ?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4997/Spying-a-file-system should help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

check the file's last modify datetime.
This method retrieves status information related to a given CFile object instance or a given file path.

BOOL GetStatus(
   CFileStatus& rStatus 
) const;
static BOOL PASCAL GetStatus(
   LPCTSTR lpszFileName,
   CFileStatus& rStatus 
);

Parameters
rStatus
A reference to a user-supplied CFileStatus structure that will receive the status information. The CFileStatus structure has the following fields:

CTime m_ctime   The date and time the file was created.

CTime m_mtime   The date and time the file was last modified.

CTime m_atime   The date and time the file was last accessed for reading.

ULONGLONG m_size   The logical size of the file in bytes, as reported by the DIR command.

BYTE m_attribute   The attribute byte of the file.

char m_szFullName[_MAX_PATH]   The absolute filename in the Windows character set.

lpszFileName
A string in the Windows character set that is the path to the desired file. The path can be relative or absolute, or it can contain a network path name.

Return Value
TRUE if the status information for the specified file is successfully obtained; otherwise, FALSE. 
PS:information from MSDN

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the infinite loop ?

Comment: i don't know.put sleep(20) in

Comment: but put sleep(20); in your loop is a good way to avoid CPU usage going too high.