# How to find out what has an EXE open in windows

Tags: windows, winapi, file-io

When you try to delete a file in Windows Explorer, and that file is in use, it brings up a dialog saying **File In Use** and it proceeds to give you the file name that has the file open.

For example,

[image: Example]

I've seen hacks involving kernel drivers, but if Windows Explorer can do it, then there must be an easier way.

What is the best and easiest way to get this information?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990535/win32-files-locked-for-reading-how-to-find-out-whos-locking-them

Comment: Use the Restart Manager. [Sample code here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/02/17/10268840.aspx).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delphi - finding the process that is accessing a file from my program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726906/delphi-finding-the-process-that-is-accessing-a-file-from-my-program)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with windows vista you can use the [`IFileIsInUse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775874%28v=vs.85%29) interface, if you want support older versions of windows you can use the [NtQuerySystemInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [NtQueryInformationFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556646%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [NtQueryObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinApi functions, for more infomation about this topic check my answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726906/delphi-finding-the-process-that-is-accessing-a-file-from-my-program).

Comment: Perfect. IFileIsInUse is what I was looking for. Thank you.